# Custom Tool for creating a cirle out of straight segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing, circle

I used to use an old tool coded by somebody that would create a circle much like the current ESRI Circle tool, but it would make the circle out of straight segments with many vertices.  The dll can not longer be registered as I believe Arc has just outgrown it (tool was made in 2003). Is anybody aware of another tool that can accomplish this same feat? The arc segments generated by the ESRI circle tool cause headaches with some of our Topology checks.

Comment: What was the name of the old tool?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of this tool? Probably nothing more than recompiling it on a more modern system will fix it?

Comment: It might still work, use EsriRegAsm to register the dll, you should be able to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAsm.exe. Like @Hornbydd said it's not a big deal to modernize provided you have the source, even converting to an addin isn't hard - but you need to have a compiler that is compatible with your ArcGIS version, the SDK for ArcObjects and some knowledge of whichever language it was written in.

Comment: By this thread https://geonet.esri.com/thread/153352 it might work by creating a buffer around a point and then simplifying the result. Same thread also has code samples for creating polygons with variable number of corners.

Comment: @MichaelStimson  Name of the tool is NewShapes.dll.  I tried registering using ESRIRegAsm (I'm new to this) but I get an error saying "c:\Data\newshapes.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try reinstalling using...".  I do not know the source code for the tool, I can only see it was last modified in 2003.  It works fine on some of our older machines so maybe its a .NET framework issue?  Is there any way I can recompile although I dont have the source code?

Comment: No, you *must* have the source code to recompile. Is there a .TLB file matching the .DLL? It's been a while since I've done COM and I vaguely remember that these files are important, I think you register the DLL but add the tool to the ArcMap customize dialog (add from file) by the TLB (v9.0 to 9.3) . The syntax of the Esri RegASM (from an old batch file I haven't removed yet) is "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAsm.exe" <Your DLL> /p:Desktop /s